# Unable to decode the json string in yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2

I am calling an `API` on a button click. API returns me a `json` response and from that response i want to get a `value`, but I am getting this error `stdClass Object ( [Message] => An error has occurred. )`.

I am using `CURL` for API call. I am getting a response but when I want to decode it it gives me the error. Below is the code.

```
 $curl = curl_init($api_url);
.....
 $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$json=json_decode($curl_response);
             print_r($curl_response);
             die();
             $meter_alive= $json->data->Response; // getting error here in the web
...
```

The `curl_response` is `{"data":{"Response":"No"}}` and `json encoded` response is `stdClass Object ( [Message] => An error has occurred. )`.

I also tried to change `$json=json_decode($curl_response);` to `$json=json_decode($curl_response, true);` and `$json=json_decode($curl_response);` to `$json=(array)json_decode($curl_response);`

But still I am unable to get the result. I don't know what is the actual problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Yii Helper:

```
use yii\helpers\Json;
```

Then in your code you can use:
`JSON::decode($curl_response)` and get Array() from Json

of instead `JSON::encode($something)`